# SWT Combo with only dropdown arrow shown

Tags: combobox, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am looking for a SWT `Combo` where only dropdown arrow is shown in order to save space.

I found that setting a `GridData.widthHint` to the width of the arrow icon on the Combo might do the trick.

The question is how do I ask the `Combo` layout the exact width of the down arrow on the Combo so that I can set that as the widthHint?

[image]

Update:

Looks like even setting the `widthHint = 0` still shows part of the text field. So any other ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a way to get the drop down button width. Messing around with the width hint is likely to be very platform dependent.

An alternative would be to use code similar to the `CCombo` control but without the `Text` field. This uses a `Button` with the `SWT.ARROW | SWT.DOWN` style:

```java
Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.ARROW | SWT.DOWN);
```

When the button is pressed an SWT `List` control is displayed.

Comment: How do I add the list control to this button so that it works the same as a Combo list?

Comment: I am going to add greg's answer to greg's answer :). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101455/how-to-display-a-popup-menu-by-mouse-left-click-in-swt) Add a selection listener to your button that shows the menu.